# Polymer Starter Kit and Polymer's indentation

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I installed the Polymer Starter Kit Light and am writing my first Polymer application.
I noticed that under `bower_componets/polymer` I have `polymer.html`, but the file has no indentation at all. I would love to follow the code and see what's going on, but the lack of indentation makes it less than ideal.

Running a simple `bower install polymer` gives you the same files.

In the GitHb project, https://github.com/Polymer/polymer , I cannot even find `polymer.html`.
So:

- How is Polymer's code structured? How is the polymer.html generated?
- How can I get a debug and tinker-friendly version of Polymer?

Comment: There is polymer.html in github repo. https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/polymer.html

Comment: True (can't believe I missed it). But... does that mean that I should be able to clone the Polymer repository and use it as is replacing "polymer" from Bower?

Comment: Polymer is imported in almost all elements. So you'll need a copy in bower_components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer has development branches and releases.

If you `bower install Polymer/polymer#master` you get the `master` **branch**, which is very much like what you see in the GitHub repository.

If you `bower install Polymer/polymer` you get the latest **release**, which has been minified (only necessary files, and those files are combined and compressed) for your production benefit.

Comment: I didn't know you could do `bower install Polymer/polymer#master -- thank you!

Comment: Scott what's the easiest way for me to have the latest *release*, but with the tabs intact? I am trying to follow what happens in my program using the Chrome debugger, and would love to do so... without having to use the latest `master` branch (in case things are not 100% working etc.)

Comment: If you look at the commit history, for any particular version you can find a main branch revision with a name like (e.g. for 1.4.0) `[ci skip] prepare v1.4.0`. If you pull that branch you should have the non-minified version of the matching release.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Polymers a bit complicated because it loads parts of itself dynamically, using the this._addFeatures function.

If you track back starting at Polymer.html, you will see it imports Polymer-mini.html which in turns imports Polymer-micro.html, which I think then loads something from the library.

Answer (score 0):

polymer.html is imported in almost all the components. So even if you change the path in your element, it will be attempted to be imported from bower_components in some other element.

From what I understand, the HTML imports system keeps track of already imported items to ensure same code is not run twice. If you have polymer.html in two different path, it might attempt to run it twice and might lead to some issues.

So it is better to leave it in bower_components.

You can also try polygit (http://polygit.org/), if you are just playing around with polymer. Below is the sample plunker with polygit

http://plnkr.co/edit/QkxrrFHYZRnlHuZVNIgy

e.g.

```
<script src="http://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
```